# Angular 2 Check Status code 200 and 400

Tags: angular, http, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to send password to my server -> server checks if it's correct password -> sends status code either: 200 success or 401 error .

Now I'm checking the status code, but it feels like there should be a better way since my code down bellow feels clunky.

I basically just want to check for those two status codes.

```
getTokenFromServer(value: Authentication): Observable <Authentication>{
        const httpOptions = {
                    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
                };

                return this.http.post(serverUrl, value, httpOptions).pipe(
                    tap((response: any) => {
                        if(response.status == "200"){
                            console.log("Success logging in: "+response.status+":"+response.token);
                            this.tokenService.setToken(response.token);                 
                        }else{
                            console.log("Error logging in: " +response.status);
                        }
                    }),
                    catchError(this.handleError('Authenticate password:'))
                    );

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Only 2xx status codes will get into your tap function, so the if check isn't necessary.  A 401 status code will result in an error being thrown, which will be cause by the `catchError` function.  You can simplify to:

```
return this.http.post(serverUrl, value, httpOptions).pipe(
    tap((response: any) => {
        console.log("Success logging in: "+response.status+":"+response.token);
        this.tokenService.setToken(response.token);                 
    }),
    catchError(this.handleError('Authenticate password:'))
);
```